# How to add default value in custom taxonomy field in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I've created custom taxonomy name "Front List" using [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) then add a custom field called "Order". I'm trying to set a default value for order. When I create any frontlist using the frontlist panel,

[image]

it's adding a default value, but when I create frontlist from "Add Post" page it's not adding any default value for "Order field".

**How to I add default value when "Front List" created from "Add Post" page?**

This is the code for adding a custom field to Frontlist taxonomy.

```
<?php
/**
 * Adding Custom Field to Taxonomy
 * @return void 
 */

function frontlists_add_order( $term ) {

    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="taxOrder"><?php _e( 'Order', 'yourtextdomain' ); ?></label>

        <input type="text" name="taxOrder" id="taxOrder" value="">
        <p>Your front List item will be sorted by this "Order". The default value is "1".</p>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'frontlists_add_form_fields', 'frontlists_add_order', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Adding Custom Field to Taxonomy in Edit Panel
 * @return void 
 */
function frontlists_edit_order( $term ) {

    $term_order = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'order', true ); 

    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th><label for="taxOrder"><?php _e( 'Order', 'yourtextdomain' ); ?></label></th>

        <td>     
            <input type="text" name="taxOrder" id="taxOrder" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term_order ) ? esc_attr( $term_order ) : ''; ?>">
            <p>Your front List item will be sorted by this "Order".</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
add_action( 'frontlists_edit_form_fields', 'frontlists_edit_order', 10 );

/**
 * Saving Custom Field to Taxonomy
 */
function frontlists_save_order( $term_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['taxOrder'] ) ) {
        $term_order = $_POST['taxOrder'];
        if( $term_order ) {
             update_term_meta( $term_id, 'order', $term_order );
        } else {
            update_term_meta( $term_id, 'order', 1 );
        }
    }

}  
add_action( 'edited_frontlists', 'frontlists_save_order' );  
add_action( 'create_frontlists', 'frontlists_save_order' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `created_term` action hook to add the new taxonomy term once it's already been added to the database. This action hook is inside the [`wp_insert_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) function. Either put this in your theme (not advised), or inside a plugin.

```php
function so_add_order_field( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ) {
    // The default order value
    $default = 1;

    // Stop if it's not the right taxonomy
    if ( 'frontlists' != $taxonomy ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Get the existing value if exists
    $order = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'taxOrder', true );

    if ( false === $order ) {
        // Add the term meta default
        add_term_meta( $term_id, 'taxOrder', $default );
    }
}
add_action( 'created_term', 'so_add_order_field', 10, 3 );
```

Then change the `$default` value to whatever you'd like it to be. This uses the [`add_term_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/) function which safely adds the meta data to the database for you. Check out the documentation for further info.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I've added this code to my function.php but it's not adding a default value, Would you please check this again?

Comment: No problem. Is it adding the value to the database? Make sure the code is run within the dashboard, a theme might not do it properly. Also check it's being added to the database with the right meta key, so make sure `taxOrder` is correct.

Comment: It's not adding value to the database, I've checked the meta key & it's "order". But still can't get working. 
Can you please tell me how to I make sure the code is run within the dashboard" ?